# How to organize class structure to inherit parameters from two classes

Tags: java, inheritance

What would be yours idea for class structure organization for application project described below. I have a some problem, because there is no multi inheritance in java and I cannot inherit Hospital class from Company class and Healthcare class, but I need to inherit parameters from both.

```
public abstract class Company {
private String name;
private Address address;
private Person manager;
private List<Person> employees;
}

public abstract class Healthcare {
private int areaForAdministration;
private int areaFirMedicineProcedures;
}

public class Investor extends Company {}

public class Designer extends Company {}

public class Department extends Healthcare {
private Hospital hospital;
}

public class Hospital extends Company, Healthcare {
private List<Department> departments;
}
```

Comment: Try using `Interfaces`?

Comment: Please take a look into Java Interfaces. You could for example have a Interface `public interface ProvidesHealthcare`. You can then have your class inherit from company and also implement the features of `ProvidesHealthcare`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that with interface I can't declare parameters which I would like to inherit in children class. If used interface in my case I should duplicate paremeters in children classes - and I am not sure if it is a good practice.